# How to Make a Box and Whisker graph with python

Tags: python, graph, median

```
import statistics

L= [0.43,0.31,0.34,0.44,0.37,0.4,0.82,0.41,0.33,0.38,0.36,0.39,0.41,0.35,0.21,0.42,0.27,0.7,0.41,0.37,0.47,0.34,0.54,0.32,0.26,0.39,0.39,0.37,0.34,0.4,0.36,0.33,0.51,0.37,0.42,0.45,0.67,0.41,0.35,0.33,0.56,0.4,0.48,0.8,0.4,0.4,0.66,0.34,0.34,0.42,0.5,0.35,0.38,0.36,0.69,0.32]
Q = [1,2,3]

x = (statistics.median(L))
y = (statistics.median(Q))
print (x,y)
```

The median for these are

```
 0.39 2
```

how do i use python to turn the medians into a box and whisker graph.

Answer (score 2):

basically is:

```
  boxplot(self, x, notch=False, sym='b+', vert=True, whis=1.5,
    positions=None, widths=None, patch_artist=False,
    bootstrap=None, usermedians=None, conf_intervals=None,
    meanline=False, showmeans=False, showcaps=True,
    showbox=True, showfliers=True, boxprops=None, labels=None,
    flierprops=None, medianprops=None, meanprops=None,
    capprops=None, whiskerprops=None, manage_xticks=True):
```

you can look at [pylab documentantion demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo.html) for box and whisker graph.

Answer (score 2):

You can use matplotlib to get a box and whisker graph.
This is a simple as

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
L= [0.43,0.31,0.34,0.44,0.37,0.4,0.82,0.41,0.33,0.38,0.36,0.39,0.41,0.35,0.21,0.42,0.27,0.7,0.41,0.37,0.47,0.34,0.54,0.32,0.26,0.39,0.39,0.37,0.34,0.4,0.36,0.33,0.51,0.37,0.42,0.45,0.67,0.41,0.35,0.33,0.56,0.4,0.48,0.8,0.4,0.4,0.66,0.34,0.34,0.42,0.5,0.35,0.38,0.36,0.69,0.32]
Q = [1,2,3]
plt.boxplot(L)
plt.show()
```

If you want both graphs in one figure, use a list like `plt.boxplot([Q,L])`.
Latter gives for my matplotlib defaults the following plot

[image]